# XStream: NamedMapConverter and HashMap without container node

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Say I have the following Java class:

```
@XStreamAlias("object")
public class MyObject {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private String name;

    private Map<String, String> description = new HashMap<>();

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Map<String, String> getDescription() { return description; }
    public void setDescription(Map<String, String> description) { this.description = description; }
}
```

How can I initialize XStream to convert it to the following XML (and parse the XML to create Java objects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<object name="test">
  <description language="en">Test en</description>
  <description language="fr">Test fr</description>
</object>
```

?

Of course I want the language to be the key of my description Map, and the node value as the map value.

I tried this :

```
XStream xs = new XStream(new DomDriver());
xs.processAnnotations(MyObject.class);
xs.registerConverter(new NamedMapConverter(xs.getMapper(), "description", "language", String.class, null, String.class, true, false, xs.getConverterLookup()));
```

But I'm getting the following ouput:

```
<object name="name test">
  <description>
    <description language="en">Test en</description>
    <description language="fr">Test fr</description>
  </description>
</object>
```

How can I get rid of the  container tag?

EDIT: I'd like to avoid writing a custom converter for the whole MyObject class since the real one is a bit complex and currently except for the description field it works without custom converter. Something similar to the NamedMapConverter would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about XStream but you can do this with [SimpleXml](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.codemonstur/simplexml).

```
public final class Question4 {

    @XmlName("object")
    public static class MyObject {
        @XmlAttribute
        private String name = "test";
        @XmlMapWithAttributes(keyName = "language")
        private Map<String, String> description = new HashMap<>();

        private MyObject() {
            description.put("en", "Test en");
            description.put("fr", "Test fr");
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
        System.out.println(parser.toXml(new MyObject()));
    }

}
```

As you can see the parser doesn't need to be configured, you only need to add the annotation to the field. The output will be this:

```
<object name="test">
  <description language="en">Test en</description>
  <description language="fr">Test fr</description>
</object>
```

The <?xml preample will not be there, but I'm sure that you can just add that yourself if it is truely required.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to stick with XStream.